# How to add i18n in the Help content toolbar and search button for an eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, internationalization, eclipse-rcp, ini

We have i18nized our help content in our eclipse RCP application. The TOC files and the HTML files they refer receive the OS nl and displays data accordingly. But the search, go button, Scope, All topics, the Help toolbar is still in English. The landing page Using the help system is also in English. I need some help how we can change it.

I have tried sending parameters in the program as well as the VM args as -nl pt,etc and tried to change the locales in the ini file of the product, but didn't worked.

Comment: You need the appropriate language packs from [Eclipse Babel](https://www.eclipse.org/babel/) for that (more precisely, for the `org.eclipse.help.webapp` plugin the fragments for the each language you want). By the way, do you know the modernized help UI that is contained in Eclipse but not enabled by default (see e.g. [here](https://remainsoftware.com/docs/openapi/help/index.jsp) vs. [leagacy](https://remainsoftware.com/docs/openapi/help/index.jsp?legacy))?

Comment: This worked for eclipse. So, we need to bundle these packages inside our RCP application ? How can we make the RCP product connected to these packages ?

Comment: Also, can we add our company specific translations ?

Comment: The fragments have to be added to the target platform and will be automatically activated with their host plugins. Yes, you can also add your own customized language pack fragments instead. If you use the modernized help UI (which I contributed to Eclipse), most languages are still missing and it would be nice if you would contribute the translations via Eclipse Babel.

Comment: I added them in target platform, and reloaded the product file. When I run it, the help is still in english.

Comment: It works for me. For example, if I build my RCP application with the fragments of the Japanese language pack so that they are placed in the `plugins` folder of my product and the `ini` file contains the two lines `-nl` and `ja` in the upper part of the `ini` file, then the help UI will be in Japanese. Without `-nl`, the language is derived from the OS.

Comment: Thanks It worked finally. I went to run configurations and added the fragments properly again then, though validate plugins showed some missing constraints but it worked. I had to work on the sanity of the jars and bundle them for the product installation.

Comment: For the help window, only one `org.eclipse.help.webapp...` fragment per language is required. You use Tycho to build your product, right? How did you include the fragments in your target definition?